# VBA- while copying date from excel to a csv the date and month digits swap places

Tags: vba, date

below are my VBA codes, its simply copying dates and values from excel to a csv and closes the CSV after saving. The problem is that when i re-open the CSV the day and month places are swapped. Something happens after the file is saved.

```
Workbooks(wb).Worksheets("values").Range("g12").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight).End(xlDown)).Copy
Workbooks(wb2).Activate
Range("a12").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("a12").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
Workbooks(wb2).Close SaveChanges:=True
```

below is an example of input values that I am coping.

[image]

Comment: What happens when you open the CSV in Notepad or some other text editor?

Comment: Open the csv in notepad, the date format likely didn't change.  When opened Excel will read a plain text date and convert it to shortdate specified by your system settings. (edit: +1 to BigBen for beating me to it)  :p

Comment: when I open in notepad++ the format is changed from dd/mm/yyyy to mm/dd/yyyy

Comment: just to add, when i manually copy paste the format doesnt change, which is quite odd.